# SMD identification - 8-pin, "OE HU"

Tags: operational-amplifier, identification

[image]

Marking code is OE HU. Thank you.

Comment: I edited your question to put the past number in the title so that someone who knows the answer might see it. Please [edit] your question and explain what the circuit board is, what you think this chip is doing, manufacturer of board and year.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [Analog Devices AD8353ACPZ](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8353.pdf) RF amplifier and the marking code is `0E`.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [aliexpress.com](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005004659881168.html?src=google&aff_fcid=7c5256ea426c4862bce61c855715f9b3-1704699105900-09557-UneMJZVf&aff_fsk=UneMJZVf&aff_platform=aaf&sk=UneMJZVf&aff_trace_key=7c5256ea426c4862bce61c855715f9b3-1704699105900-09557-UneMJZVf&terminal_id=bf341379b04f4d21b63bbccb56305de5&afSmartRedirect=y))